# obtener correctamente valores decimales en controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

he creado una vista basada en un modelo utilizando MVC C# en este modelo tengo una propiedad para el costo de un evento, el cual segun mi pais puede contener los siguientes valores validos (separo por guion medio): $1,234,56 - $123,123,54 - $1.25 y la propiedad con validaciones utilizando data annotations es:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage="Especifique precio evento")]
        [Display(Name="Precio Evento")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]      
        [RegularExpression(@"^(((\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(.\d+)?$", ErrorMessage = "Error")]

        public double PrecioEvento { get; set; }
```

mi problema es que al dar enviar a mi formulario, en el controller recibo bien estos valores 1.25 - 25.47 - 789.32 de PrecioEvento...pero cuando el valor especificado para PrecioEvento lleva una coma por ejemplo 123,123.45 recibo 0.0 en mi controller.

al principio cada vez que escribia un numero con punto decimal recibia cero en mi controller pero lo arregle agregando esto a mi web.config

```
<globalization culture="es-SV"/>
```

pero ahora no se que debo modificar para obtener en mi controller valores especificados en mi vista que tengan coma (de miles) y punto decimal, por ejemplo: 123,123,45.

Gracias por la ayuda, Nota: la expresion regular que utilizo funciona para obtener los valores deseados (coma de miles y punto decimal).

Comment: Una consideración importante. Mucha gente usa `double` para trabajar con moneda. Esto no es lo mejor y puede provocar problemas de redondeos extraños, ya que es un tipo de datos de coma flotante y puede perderse precisión. Para trabajar con monedas, el tipo correcto es siempre `decimal`

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso del error es que por la coma el valor es recibe es un string cuando tu variable PrecioEvento es double

Te recomiendo que utilices formatos prediseñado. Este es un ejemplo:

```
  String.Format("{0:#,0.000}", value)
```

Lo puedes aplicar desde tu model

```
public double PrecioEvento { get; set; }
public double strPrecioEvento { get
    {
        return String.Format("{0:#,0.000}", PrecioEvento );
    }
    set
    {
        PrecioEvento = value;
    } 
}
```

y utiliza strPrecioEvento  en tu vista en vez de PrecioEvento

Comment: gracias, una pregunta: a la propiedad double PrecioEvento debere colocarle las validaciones de data annotations ?  tambien una observacion, si coloco return String.Format("{0:#,0.000}", PrecioEvento ); me señala el error: the name string does not exist in the current context y si cambio la S mayuscula de String por s minuscula entonces me señala el error: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

Comment: No, en este caso las anotaciones pasarían al strPrecioEvento ya que está será el elemnto que interactua con la vista; PrecioEvento solo se encarga de tomar el valor. El punto es dar la conversión adecuada para la vista y los datos se mantengan integros.

Comment: tambien una observacion, si coloco return String.Format("{0:#,0.000}", PrecioEvento ); me señala el error: the name string does not exist in the current context y si cambio la S mayuscula de String por s minuscula entonces me señala el error: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double' –

Comment: hay que converitr el doble a string, intenta con PrecioEvento .ToString();

Comment: yo lo resolvi de esta manera: return Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:#,0.000}", PrecioEvento)); me funciona la parte de los ceros despues del punto, pero la coma no se visualiza en los numeros